# How to solve the warning message about "But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response" in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb

I called HTTP endpoint and get correct response.

But I don't know why the warning message as below in EI log.

How can I do to solve this warning? Thank you.

```
Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:f1d3d901-322e-4ac2-ad28-5c4fd3c97aa5 But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that I was getting these errors on latency between the executing WSO2 EI thread and certain clients (mainly IIS hosted sites)

After approx 120 seconds after receiving the expected response, the client would send a TCP RST, ACT command back to WSO2.  This seems to cause the SynapseCallbackReceiver warning:

`[2019-09-12 10:57:20,776] [] DEBUG - SynapseCallbackReceiver Callback added. Total callbacks waiting for : 1
[2019-09-12 10:57:20,925] [] DEBUG - SynapseCallbackReceiver Callback removed for request message id : urn:uuid:f269f019-9c2f-4b7d-81a1-d6e447687c90. Pending callbacks count : 0
........
[2019-09-12 10:59:19,137] []  WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:f269f019-9c2f-4b7d-81a1-d6e447687c90 But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response`

As the WSO2 EI default for KEEP-ALIVE is TRUE, by setting it to FALSE forces the Client to close the session and no further TCP requests are sent.

Disable KEEP-ALIVE using the following:

`<property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" value="true" scope="axis2"/>`

However, this can increase latency between the WSO2 EI and the client as all requests are handled as separate connections. I am not sure whether the additional latency is less beneficial than the EI handling delayed TCP RST requests.

See [WSO2 ESB Keep Alive Property](https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/wso2-esb-keep-alive-property/)

Answer (score 0):

The warning message will be logged from `SynapseCallbackReceiver` if there is no callback available for the message received.

Probable causes:

1. This happens when the client has time out before receiving the response.
2. Consider using the `OUT_ONLY` property for messages which are sent / forwarded from EI / ESB. 
   This will prevent the ESB from registering **unnecessary callbacks** for response handling and also eventually running out of memory.

Refer the following resource.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-OUT_ONLY

Comment: But I didn't use the OUT_ONLY property in my program.

Comment: @Amanda you should consider using it, to avoid unnecessary callback and thereby improve the performance as well

Comment: Therefore I add this property in my program can solve this issue?

Comment: I have used the OUT_ONLY property but it can't get the http response....This is not what I want.

Comment: Should not use out_only for service where response is needed. But use it where fire and forget is needed, both internal services like DSS or other backend services

Comment: But all my endpoints needed response, therefore out_only can't use in my program.

Comment: if so, then the other reason can be as stated in my first point. debug with that perspective.

Comment: I have increased 1 hour timeout but the warning message not disappeared.

Comment: @Muralidharan.rade, I have the same problem and the first case is my problem. The fact is the endpoint I am calling is not stable and has a problem. I set the proper time out and execute the fault sequence but the WARN message eventually the ESB will be not responding.